# change size of error message is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following error message and I want to change the height of it,
I tried with the following (.css("height:10px;");) and this is not working,any idea 
what is missing

```
$messages.html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>").css("height:10px;");
```

Comment: Why can't you just add the style tag in your html string itself rather than using jQuery for it?

Comment: Are you trying to give the height to the messages elements or the new div you are creating? if the former,  then Don is correct

Comment: [Please read the manual first…](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the alert boxes in the **Twitter bootstrap** will use the `alert class`. This sets the styling which all the alert boxes will use but for the other boxes we will just change the colours to match the scenario.

```
.alert {
padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px;
margin-bottom: 18px;
color: #c09853;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
background-color: #fcf8e3;
border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert-heading {
color: inherit;
}

.alert .close {
position: relative;
top: -2px;
right: -21px;
line-height: 18px;
}
```

The HTML to call these are very simple just add the CSS class to a outer div or paragraph tag.

```
<div class="alert">Example of an alert box.</div>
```

### Success

The success alert box will be used when the user successfully completes a task all the CSS will do is override the colours of the standard alert box.

```
.alert-success {
color: #468847;
background-color: #dff0d8;
border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
```

When you use this CSS class you need to use both the alert CSS and the alert-success CSS.

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Example of the successful alert box</div>
```

### Danger or Error

The error alert box works the same as the success box it is just used to change the colour of the background and text.

```
.alert-danger,
.alert-error {
color: #b94a48;
background-color: #f2dede;
border-color: #eed3d7;
}
```

Again you need to use both the alert CSS and the alert-error CSS.

### Information

The last style is the information style, used to highlight a message to the user by just using the CSS class alert-info.

```
.alert-info {
color: #3a87ad;
background-color: #d9edf7;
border-color: #bce8f1;
}
```

### Styling Blocks

Along with the different scenario styling Twitter bootstrap also gives you additional CSS classes to further style the alert boxes.

Adding a class of alert-block you increase the padding of the box.

```
.alert-block {
padding-top: 14px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

The next styling will reduce the margins on the paragraph tags inside the alert-block.

```
.alert-block &gt; p,
.alert-block &gt; ul {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.alert-block p + p {
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

The HTML to add additional padding can be used by adding the alert-block CSS class to one of the alert boxes.

```
<div class="alert alert-information alert-block">
Example of the information alert box
</div>
```

That's all the alert boxes you currently get with the Twitter bootstrap, You can Change/Modify alert box as per your requirement. This was the basic informations which is repeatedly asked by many people. I hope this information helps many people. If you feel this answer useful to you somewhere, somehow...Please Up-Vote this answer. Thanks.. ;)

Comment: @Jean : you can set height of class="alert alert-danger" in CSS

Comment: i've try it like following and its not working .alert alert-danger {
    height: 10px;
}

Comment: put comma(,) sign like .alert-danger,
.alert-error{ height: 10px;}

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick by altering your code for setting height

```
css("height","10px")
```

Check the full code here

```
 $messages.html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>").css("height","10px");
```

But what you need this to be done via jquery if you are sure what you want at the beginning?
You can rather do it like this as well.

```
$messages.html("<div class='alert alert-danger' style='height:10px;'><strong>Error : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
```

Comment: Thanks KD but this just change the position of the window...I want to change the window size to be smaller...,any idea?

Comment: By window... did you mean the browser window? does that means that you are opening new window in your application?

Comment: No,when the error message is appear in the page you see it inside of rectangle ,I want to reduce the size of this rectangle ,how should I do that?

Comment: As you are using bootstrap i think this is not height but the padding which could be making the container bit bigger. I would rather suggest to make changes in css as per your choice or check the padding which is applied in .alert-danger class. This will help you to get what you want.

Comment: I've tried with .css("padding", "50px"); but the rectangle postion in the screen was change and not the size of it...

Comment: can you add the screen shot to have a look

Answer (score 1):

its suppose to be like this

```
$messages.html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>").css("height","10px");
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that `;` (semicolon) outside, it's pretty hard to identify how your code is different from OPs code :)

Comment: Thanks Don but this just change the position of the window...I want to change the window size to be smaller...,any idea?